# create 2 columns based on one date column on a where condition

Tags: sql, parsing

I would like to parse out a date column into 2 columns based on a where condition by StatusCode.

My query is:

```sql
select OrderID, StatusCode, Date_stamp 
from xyz where StatusCode ='Shipped'
left join 
select OrderID, StatusCode, Date_stamp 
from xyz where StatusCode ='Ordered'
```

I tried to bring the query again and simply do a left join on OrderID and bringing in only the Date_stamp column based on where = ordered thinking it would roll up the data into a single record. Any guidance is appreciated.

```
| OrderID  | StatusCode | Date_stamp | 
| -------- | ---------  | --------   |
| 1        | Ordered    | 1/1/2024   |
| 1        | Shipped    | 1/5/2024   |
| 2        | Ordered    | 1/22/2024  |
| 2        | null       | null       |
```

expected results:

| OrderID | StatusCode | OrderedDate | Shipped Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Shipped | 1/1/2024 | 1/5/2024 |
| 2 | Ordered | 1/22/2024 | null |

Comment: Is it possible that the `Date_stamp` might be the same for both `Ordered` and `Shipped` StatusCode? If so, on this output, which StatusCode should be displayed and why? Ultimately, I think that's going to be the trickier problem to solve. You just haven't run into it yet since you are stuck on this "Pivot" logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This should give the expected output -**

```
SELECT OrderID, max(StatusCode), max(OrderedDate), max(ShippedDate)
FROM(
SELECT OrderID, StatusCode, 
CASE WHEN StatusCode = 'Ordered' then Date_stamp else Null end as OrderedDate,
CASE WHEN StatusCode = 'Shipped' then Date_stamp else Null end as ShippedDate
from xyz) as temp
GROUP BY OrderID
```